# Delphi TIdhttp Post JSON?

Tags: php, json, delphi, indy

Anybody getting JSON to work with TIdHttp ?

The PHP always return NULL in the `$_POST`, am I doing anything wrong ?

Delphi source:

```
http := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
http.HandleRedirects := True;
http.ReadTimeout := 5000;
http.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
jsonToSend := TStringStream.Create('{"name":"Peter Pan"}');
jsonToSend.Position := 0;
Memo1.Lines.Text := http.Post('http://www.website.com/test.php', jsonToSend);
jsonToSend.free;
http.free;
```

PHP source:

```
<?php
$value = json_decode($_POST);
var_dump($value);
?>
```

Comment: Consider using `var_dump($_POST)` to see what it is you're asking your program to decode.

Comment: For this code, `var_dump($_POST)` produces `array(0) {}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use a `TStringList` to post JSON data.  `TIdHTTP.Post()` will encode the `TStringList` contents in a way that breaks the JSON data.  You need to put the JSON data into a `TStream` instead. `TIdHTTP.Post()` will transmit its contents as-is.  Also, don't forget to set the `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentType` property so the server knows you are posting JSON data.

Comment: Your answer was the correct answer, though.  To post raw JSON data and have it accepted using the original PHP code, a `TStream` needs to be used instead of a `TStringList`, just like you showed. The only error in your answer is you are setting `Request.ContentEncoding` to UTF-8, which is wrong because UTF-8 is not a valid content encoding. It belongs in `Request.CharSet` instead.

Comment: Remy, I accepted the above becoz it seemed to work, but not sure in the long run. `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentType` should be to `application/json`? Also, do you mean I can opt out the `json=` part?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I changed it as you suggested (see code above) using `TStringStream`. I still get `NULL` from `json_decode($_POST)` though.

Comment: I did a little research and found the original PHP script is wrong in using `$_POST` in the first place. That only works when posting name/value pairs, which the JSON stream is not. The PHP script needs to use `php://input` instead to access the raw JSON data, eg: `$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a post variable, try this code (I have added "json" var to your code):

Delphi code:

```
http := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
http.HandleRedirects := true;
http.ReadTimeout := 5000;
jsonToSend := TStringList.create;
jsonToSend.Text := 'json={"name":"Peter Pan"}';
Memo1.Lines.Text := http.Post('http://www.website.com/test.php', jsonToSend);
jsonToSend.free;
http.free;
```

PHP source:

```
<?php
$value = json_decode($_POST['json']);
var_dump($value);
?>
```

Comment: I still get NULL, but when I do "var_dump($_POST)" I get the array. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to trace what's going out of your application e.g. using WireShark or similar tools ? I don't know anything about the PHP part, but at least your Delphi part have some issues.

Comment: Seemed the slashes were the culprit, I changed it to `$value = stripcslashes($_POST['json'])`, now working fine

Comment: @Atlas, try to learn how to use safe `try..finally` blocks. In your code as well as in this post, the `IdHTTP` may fail because Indy is driven by exceptions, what may easily cause memory leaks in your application. And anyway, does your code work without change of the request content type ?

Comment: @TLama, yes I will use the `try..finally`, the source above is just for a simpler view, not the production version. Yes, it seemed to work without ContentType, which was weird... Sometimes Indy drives me crazy...