# how to post json using THTTPClient in delphi?

Tags: json, delphi, post

I know how to send a post request using THTTPClient, but how to post json?
my code:

```
 var
      http: THTTPClient;
      params: TStringList;
    begin
      http:= THTTPClient.Create;
      params:= TStringList.Create;
      params.Add('login=admin');
      params.Add('password=123456');
      http.Post('http://localhost/login', params);
```

my json:

```
{
    "login": "admin",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

Comment: Have you seen <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025646/delphi-http-post-json>

Comment: @RaoufRahiche yes, i have. there is different component

Comment: @Michael: If you [read the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient.Post), `THTTPClient.Post()` has several overloads, one of which can post a `TStream`, just like the `TIdHTTP.Post()` method can in the example that Raouf pointed to. A lot of Embarcadero's HTTP and REST framework design is inspired by Indy's components, since that is what Embarcadero used to use before venturing out with their own frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to be sure that the URL you are posting accepts json on posts and you also have to specify in a header that you want to send a JSON to the URL.

the header is:

```
Content-Type:application/json
```